# how to find smart TV which support HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sdk, television

I search in google, but not able to find what smart TV's browsers support HTML5 and CSS3, and javascript and AJAX. I want know the model of each TV, with 32 inches that support these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The list is not per model, rather per year. You can find it here: 
[SmartTV specifications](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec)